# changing text value in async action using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

Inside view I have

```
  <a onclick="myAction(@item.Id)" id="myActionId">@actionText</a>
```

or

```
<a id="myActionId" onclick="myAction(21)">Activate</a>
```

fuction which sends id to mvc controller to process further. As a response from controller I'm getting string data which should be used to change button text without reload page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">              
  function myAction(someId){
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/mydata/someaction/",
            data: { id: someId}
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            $("#myActionId").text(msg);            
        });
    }    
</script>
```

I'm receiving correct text inside done(function(msg)) but button text is not updated with that value. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: For front-end questions I recommend showing the rendered HTML, not the razor view. Just in case something is happening during the render which has changed your ID for example.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console? Have you tried running the code in the console? For example: `$("#myActionId").text("test");`

Comment: yes, inside console.log I'm getting expected (correct) value. Just value is not refreshed inside ui.

Comment: Add option  `dataType:'text',` in your `$.ajax` and check again...

Comment: Also, check if you have duplicate ids. There shouldn't be another element with `#myActionId` as its id.

Comment: @denat you were right

Answer (score 0):

user `$('#mybutton').val("My NEW Text");`
have look at demo [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t9pk1jq3/)

Answer (score 0):

ajax method default is `Asynchronous:true`.in your code, `myAction(someId)` function `return as true default`.so,before get result from ajax method.your MyAction() funciton is in  inactive status.due to this you are not able to set text in your anchor tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">              
function myAction(someId){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/mydata/someaction/",
        async: false,
        data: { id: someId}
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        $("#myActionId").text(msg);            
    });
}
```